# Assign Buttons Wacom Intuos Pro M

Tags: wacom

After installing Ubuntu 22.04(wayland ), I tried to assign keystrokes to the buttons of my wacom tablet, but, the system does not let me select the option, in general it does not let me select any of the options.
Has anyone an idea how to fix it?

Note: in ubuntu 20.04 I could assign keystrokes to each button on my tablet.

Comment: Same issue for X11 also in Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Same for me, Wacom Cintiq Companion 2